# password .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Bom dia a todos, entao galera eu estou montando um servidor de filmes e tenho varios filmes em uma vps e meu site esta alojado na hostgator.
Tem como eu por uma senha com .htaccess no meu vps e fazer a autenticação com o método post? Por que ai antes de pegar o filme eu enviaria um post do meu site para o vps, se a comunicação entre o site e a vps estivesse tudo okay eu reproduziria, caso contrario eu não reproduziria.

Comment: Deve ser disso que você está falando:  https://devblog.drall.com.br/o-comando-htpasswd-do-apache

Comment: Não exatamento jhonatan, em parte isso resolveria mas teria que ter uma forma de desbloquear fazendo uma requisição post.